# Find the Fill value of a rectangle inside a comboboxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have following xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_les_3.Oefening_4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Oefening_4" Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel Width="auto" Margin="20px">
    <ComboBox Width="100" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Selected" x:Name="comboBox">
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" Red"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" Yellow"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" Green"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

As you see, inside my ComboboxItems I have a rectangle and a textblock. Now I want to retreive the fill color of the rectangle (or the text of the textblock, it's the same) when my selectionchanged event is handled, so I can change the background of the window according to the selected color (which is the goal of the excercise).

Comment: No, not yet, but if I can solve it that way, it's okay.

Comment: bind your `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to a `List<System.Windows.Media.Color>` and use it's `SelectedItem` property to find out what color is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above, this is the **Correct** way to achieve what you need in WPF:

First of all, create a proper **ViewModel** that contains the list of available colors and a SelectedColor property:

```
public class ColorsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Colors { get; private set; }

    private string _selectedColor;
    public string SelectedColor
    {
        get { return _selectedColor; }
        set
        {
            _selectedColor = value;
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Color: " + value); //message box here to show the code is actually working.
        }
    }

    //... More code here in a moment
}
```

Then, make sure you populate the color collection with relevant data. In the case of colors specifically, WPF has built-in TypeConverters that can convert from (for example) `string` to `System.Windows.Media.Color` implicitly, therefore we can leverage that to simplify our code and use simple strings:

```
    //Continuation of the above code
    public ColorsViewModel()
    {
        Colors = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "Red",
            "Green",
            "Blue",
            "Yellow",
        };
    }
```

And finally create the UI in XAML using proper [**DataBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor}"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That one is very clear for me, and together with the solution of JPone ,I have two ways.

Answer (score 1):

The change event is fired and the ComboBox.SelectedItem has the info you need.
You have to analyze the SelectedItem like my following method:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = this.comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if (comboBoxItem != null)
        {
            StackPanel stackPanel = comboBoxItem.Content as StackPanel;
            if(stackPanel != null && stackPanel.Children[0] is Rectangle)
            {
                var fill = (stackPanel.Children[0] as Rectangle).Fill;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here you get the fill of the rectangle and can handle this or do your stuff.
But be patient, this code is created exactly for you sample (ComboBoxItem with Content StackPanel with Children[0] as Rectangle). Changes will iterrupt the process ;)

Comment: -1. This goes against all known established, accepted, recommended good practices and patterns in WPF. Your code is completely prone to be totally broken upon the most subtle change in the Visual Tree. What if I change the `StackPanel` for a `Grid` in XAML?

Comment: I commented that this code sample is exactly for the given sample. In case of choosing another solution i would prefer a own DataTemplate and a DataObject containing "Color, Name" and bind it via Collection to the ComboBox. The SelectedItem of the ComboBox should be bind into the viewmodel and all changed can be handled from there.